# Какие есть библиотеки Python для создания перетаскиваемых объектов?

Tags: python, android, объекты, kivy

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть библиотеки Python и какие лучше использовать для создания перетаскиваемых объектов в приложении **под Андроид**?(использую Kivy)
Перетаскиваемы объекты будут использоваться в представлении линейных уравнений, пример:
[image: линейное уравнение]

Comment: Посмотрите это, может быть подойдёт: https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/kivy-tutorial/touch-input-mouse-input/

Answer (score 0):

В kivy самом можно создавать такие объекты, пример документации с перетаскиваемым Label: [kivy документация](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.drag.html)